# Example keystore with an RSA keypair and a certificate chain

Tags: java, keystore, keytool

I have to test some encryption stuff for which I need a java keystore ([jks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html)) which contains an RSA keypair and a key chain. I found descriptions ([here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=407886&seqNum=3), [here](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1352403-java-codesigning-jks-method---certificate-generation-and-installation)) which either:

1. needed an official certificate (Verisign, globalsign - which I don't have)
2. or involved openSSL (need a self contained example **only** based on java's keytool.exe)

Is there an existing keystore available (most convienient ;-) or a description on how I am able to generate one with *racle's keytool?

Comment: this should help you: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfen/index.html).
I'm pretty sure you don't need official cert. You can generate it yourself with openssl for example. Good enough for testing

Comment: I guess creating a self-signed certificate in a JKS is not what you are asking for? You would also want the self-signed certificate to be part of a certificate chain?

Comment: No - i am able to create a self signed certificate already however not with a certificate chain...